# How can I put a profile photo for a Microsoft teams bot?

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-teams, photo, microsoft-graph-teams

I have an application hosted media bot and I want to change it's profile picture when I add it to a teams meeting.

I am able to set an icon using bot channel registration settings.
Kindly suggest how I can set image like we can change the profile photo of all users on Microsoft teams.

Regards,
Aarushi

Answer (score 5):

This is currently not possible. You can go to [Uservoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) and raise a feature request.

Comment: I have raised a feature request here : https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/41310469-set-up-profile-picture-for-application-hosted-medi